# Bootstrap Dropdown on mobile phones strange behavior

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, joomla

I use bootstrap and joomla and got an very strange issue ... if i use the "normal" navigation, everything works fine .. if I reduce the size of the browser window the collapsed menu icon shows up. If I click it shows the menu and also the dropdown menu. If I just click on it without moving anything, nothing happens ... if I move the mouse, the subitems show up ...

the strangest part is ... on mobile phones I can open the collapsed menu, but if I click on the dropdown nothing happens ... If I zoom in very wide sometimes if I touch very often onto the arrow the menu shows up ...

I'm going crazy !!!

You can find the page on

http://buero.marketing-inspiration.com/mutpol_de_neu/

Thank you for your help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your template is loading two different versions of Bootstrap js, Joomla's (2.3.2) and 3.3.1. I'd expect that to cause issues in a number of areas.

Whichever way you go you need to ensure that the markup you use is appropriate to the Bootstrap version you are using.

Personally, I'd go with current Bootstrap and disable the Joomla versions with a system plugin. I can highly recommend this one:

https://github.com/phproberto/plg_sys_mootable

Comment: Thank you, I tried the plugin but nothing changes in the behavior :)

Comment: You have to enable the plugin and then add the paths to scripts you want removed, e.g. /media/jui/js/bootstrap.min.js, in the plugin settings.

Answer (score 0):

You can try fix this in CSS code to specific resolution disable, enable or add different css configs like this:

```
@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .uk-dropdown-grid > [class*='uk-width-'] {
    width: 100%;
  }
  .uk-dropdown-grid > [class*='uk-width-']:nth-child(n+2) {
    margin-top: 30px;
  }
}
```

Comment: Hey ... thank you for your suggestion ... I know that I can use this one to change the behavior in different resolutions. But this is not solving my problem ... It doesn't depend on the resolution. If I "simulate" a small resolution in firefox on my PC the dropdown will show up ... if I try it on my smartphone (android / chrome) nothing happens ...